# Exception from hresult 0x80040501 Error with .xls files

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I used a few ArcPy lines of code to identify some water wells that had incorrect coordinates and then turned them into .xls files. The code worked well, an in short order I had a spreadsheet for each county I was working on. I keep getting a `exception from hresult 0x80040501` error when trying to load the point into ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0. I'm confident that the outlying wells have been properly identified, but I can't verify that when I try to bring the spreadsheets back into ArcGIS Pro. I can get it to work if I manually save the spreadsheet as a .xlsx however.

When I try to add the file to ArcGIS the system says that I have an empty container on several of the files.

I've seen that other people have had similar errors before, but I'm not using the tools that they were using. Have any suggestions?

````
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("MI_Counties", "NEW_SELECTION", "NAME = 'Wexford'", None)

# SELECT OUTLYING WELLS
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation("Wexford_WaterWells", "INTERSECT", "MI_Counties", None, "NEW_SELECTION", "INVERT")

# CONVERT TO .XLS
arcpy.conversion.TableToExcel("Wexford_WaterWells", r"C:\Users\BarnbyJ\Documents\Projects\Water_Well_Outliers\Outliers\Wexford_Water_Well_Outliers.xls", "ALIAS", "CODE")```
````

Comment: What is the full error message, including line number, that results from running the code that you've presented?

Comment: That was the entirety of the error message. I wasn't getting the error when running the code. The error message appeared when I would try to add the .xls tables to my project. I couldn't load the tables because ArcGIS wouldn't see the actual worksheet within the workbook. It was weird. 

I ended up converting everything to .xlsx and everything worked fine. I still don't understand why things didn't work right though.